# Perguntas solicitando maiores detalhes sobre um determinado conteúdo são inapropriadas?

Tags: suporte

Sem querer parecer prepotente, gostaria de saber se existe algum problema com a pergunta que fiz recentemente. Seria porque o tema que eu tomei como base para realizar a pergunta data de 2016, ou simplesmente porque ela é uma pergunta ruim mesmo, ampla demais ou algo do tipo, se o motivo for por ser um pergunta ruim por que ela não esta com downvotes?

Base para a minha pergunta: [O que é uma condição de corrida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159342/o-que-%c3%a9-uma-condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-corrida?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Pergunta em questão: [Porque o sistema operacional deixa a cargo do programador tratar condições de corrida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369427/porque-o-sistema-operacional-deixa-a-cargo-do-programador-tratar-condi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a sua pergunta não recebeu *up* ou *downvotes* é algo que não se pode saber. Provavelmente passou despercebido ou ninguém se interessou na sua pergunta, ao ponto de nem votar ou buscar entender e postar um comentário ou mesmo uma resposta.

Nesses casos, se você tem pelo menos 50 pontos de reputação, é oferecer uma recompensa para que os usuários, no mínimo, deem mais atenção à sua pergunta e proponham uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Nenhum grande problema com a pergunta, apenas as pessoas não se interessaram.

Tem alguns pequenos problemas. Ela parte de algumas premissas erradas (perguntas geralmente fazem isto, afinal se a pessoa soubesse tudo sobre o assunto ela não estaria perguntando).

Mudei a situação lá.